# PN200 replacement

Tags: design

I have circuit that is calling for a PN200 PNP Transitor. However, those are not avaiable in my area.  Can anyone suggest a replacement transitor.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This [discussion](http://www.edaboard.com/thread31793.html) suggests [NTE159](http://www.nteinc.com/specs/100to199/pdf/nte159.pdf), [BC557](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/BC556_557.pdf), or [2N3906](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/2N/2N3906.pdf).

A useful way to find such parts is to search for e.g. "pn200 cross reference"

Comment: "Pn200 cross reference" is that my password for google?